# ActionController::UnknownFormat when I use respond_to + respond_with (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't understand what's happening, when I ask for index action I receive ActionController::UnknownFormat, even existing a index.js file inside views/products folder. Anyone can help me to figure out what I'm missing out? I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0.0-p247.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
  def index
    @products = Product.published.newest.page(params[:page])
    respond_with @products
  end

end
```

Comment: have you tried renaming your file to index.js.erb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the format on the petition, i.e:

get :show, :user_id => user_id, :format => :json